# Ecplise P2: Validate repository location

Tags: eclipse-rcp, p2

I am developing an RCP application and providing update functionality to user.

I am converting String urls to java.net.URI and validating them with following code:

1. convert string urls to URI
2. Validate URIs
3. Load repositories to make sure a valid artifacts.xml or artifacts.jar exist and repository can be used for update.

   private String[] repositories = { "http://myrepo.com/TEST_REPO/",
           "http://myrepo.com/TEST_REPO1/" };

   @Override
   public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
       List uris = new ArrayList();
       URI uri = null;
       for (String str : this.repositories) {
           try {
               uri = new URI(str);
       if (uri != null) {
           uris.add(uri);
       }
           } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

   final ProvisioningUI ui = ProvUIActivator.getDefault()
           .getProvisioningUI();
   for (URI u : uris) {
       IStatus status = ui.getRepositoryTracker()
           .validateRepositoryLocation(ui.getSession(), uri, true,
                   null);

   ```
   if (!status.isOK()) {
   MessageDialog.open(MessageDialog.ERROR, Display.getDefault()
           .getActiveShell(), "P2 Repo Status", status
           .getMessage(), 0);
   }
   ```

   }

   for (URI repo : uris) {
       try {
       IArtifactRepository repository = ProvUI
               .getArtifactRepositoryManager(ui.getSession())
               .loadRepository(repo, null);

   ```
   if (repository != null) {
           System.out.println(repository.getName());
   }
   } catch (ProvisionException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
   ```

   } catch (Exception ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }
   }
       return null;
   }

Here 3rd point, loading repository, is there any better way to validate whether repository is valid and can be used for update. The problem with current approach is, if repository is invalid, it takes huge time to determine. Application gets stuck. Kindly guide me.

Comment: Forgive me for code formatting, it is giving little tough time. Don't know why it isn't working :(